# Is running tests on simulator with older iOS version possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

1. Create an new iOS project using Xcode 8.0
2. Run tests on simulator running iOS 10 -> tests passes
3. Run tests on simulator running iOS 8.1 -> tests failed with the following log

Log

```
16:31:59.249 Xcode[1084:43771] Test operation failure: Canceling tests due to timeout in Waiting for test process to check in...
16:31:59.249 Xcode[1084:43771] _finishWithError:Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Canceling tests due to timeout in Waiting for test process to check in..." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Canceling tests due to timeout in Waiting for test process to check in...} didCancel: 1
```

However running the app on simulator running iOS 8.1 works fine.

Comment: What is the test?

Comment: Yes... it is possible.

Comment: Works fine here under iOS 8.4.

Comment: @artem-novichkov the test is default test xcode gives, which is only method declaration. I just want to make sure the tests are run.

Comment: @shallowThought Tried again using iOS 8.4 and still getting the same failing results... Are you using Xcode 8.0 or Xcode 8.1?

Comment: Xcode 8.1. Maybe post a link to a minimal example project.